# outlook 2010 addin c#::: custom form does not work on client computer

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am developing an addin for Outlook 2010 with Visual Studio in C#.
I created a custom ribbon with a button. Once you click the button, it loads a form where you can generate a special appointment.
It works great on my development computer. But when I install it on another computer (without Visual Studio, but with installed .net framework and vsto), the ribbon with the button loads, but the creation of the form instance fails.

I have created a form in my Project named frmBZAppointment. This is my button onclick listener (which works perfect on my dev pc, but not on another pc)

```
public partial class CustomerRibbon
{
    private void butCustomAppointment_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test 1"); //works
        frmBZAppointment frm = new frmBZAppointment();
        MessageBox.Show("test 2"); //does not work
        frm.Show();
        MessageBox.Show("test 3"); //does not work
    }
}
```

I've already finished [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) guide

It would be great if someone has an idea what it could be.

---

EDIT:

solved the problem

I had to add "Microsoft Visual Basic PowerPacks 10" to my installation prerequisites.

Comment: Are you sure all the required DLLs are on the machine which is not working and they and in the GAC?

Comment: what error does it give or what is in the event viewer?

Comment: @KOL it does not give any error. It just don't display the form

Comment: @KOL I will have a closer look at the DLL's

Comment: are you using any third party control like infragistics in form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class CustomerRibbon 
{ 
    private void butCustomAppointment_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
    { 
        try
        {
            frmBZAppointment frm = new frmBZAppointment(); 
            frm.Show(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Luke94 - what was the root issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try turning on **[Add-in user interface errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx)** in Outlook Advanced Options.

Comment: thanks you. I solved it with dkackman's suggestion, but your tip is also good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but found there was a whole list of things that aren't included in the prerequisites.

I followed the page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx). Most notably the VSTO runtime is not part of the VSTO install package by default. So that's nice.